# Combinatorial explosion while merging dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas

I'm trying to merge a series of dataframes in pandas. I have a list of dfs, `dfs` and a list of their corresponding labels `labels` and I want to merge all the dfs into 1 df in such that the common labels from a df get the suffix from its label in the `labels` list. i.e.:

```
def mymerge(dfs, labels):
  labels_dict = dict([(d, l) for d, l in zip(dfs, labels)])
  merged_df = reduce(lambda x, y:
                     pandas.merge(x, y, 
                                  suffixes=[labels_dict[x], labels_dict[y]]),
                     dfs)
  return merged_df
```

When I try this, I get the error:

```
pandas.tools.merge.MergeError: Combinatorial explosion! (boom)
```

I'm trying to make a series of merges that at each merge grows at most by number of columns N, where N is the number of columns in the "next" df in the list. The final DF should have as many columns as all the df columns added together, so it grow additively and not be combinatorial.

The behavior I'm looking for is: Join dfs on the column names that are specified (e.g. specified by `on=`) or that the dfs are indexed by. Unionize the non-common column names (as in outer join). If a column appears in multiple dfs, optionally overwrite it. Looking more at the docs, it sounds like `update` might be the best way to do this. Though when I try `join='outer'` it raises an exception signaling that it's not implemented.

**EDIT**:

Here is my attempt at an implementation of this, which does not handle suffixes but illustrates the kind of merge I'm looking for:

```
def my_merge(dfs_list, on):
    """ list of dfs, columns to merge on. """
    my_df = dfs_list[0]
    for right_df in dfs_list[1:]:
        # Only put the columns from the right df
        # that are not in the existing combined df (i.e. new)
        # or which are part of the columns to join on
        new_noncommon_cols = [c for c in right_df \
                              if (c not in my_df.columns) or \
                                 (c in on)]
        my_df = pandas.merge(my_df,
                             right_df[new_noncommon_cols],
                             left_index=True,
                             right_index=True,
                             how="outer",
                             on=on)
    return my_df
```

This assumes that the merging happens on the indices of each of the dfs. New columns are added in an outer-join style, but columns that are common (and not part of the index) are used in the join via the `on=` keyword.

Example:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame([{"employee": "bob",
                         "gender": "male",
                         "bob_id1": "a"},
                        {"employee": "john",
                         "gender": "male",
                         "john_id1": "x"}])
df1 = df1.set_index("employee")
df2 = pandas.DataFrame([{"employee": "mary",
                         "gender": "female",
                         "mary_id1": "c"},
                        {"employee": "bob",
                         "gender": "male",
                         "bob_id2": "b"}])
df2 = df2.set_index("employee")
df3 = pandas.DataFrame([{"employee": "mary",
                         "gender": "female",
                         "mary_id2": "d"}])
df3 = df3.set_index("employee")
merged = my_merge([df1, df2, df3], on=["gender"])
print "MERGED: "
print merged
```

The twist on this would be one where you arbitrarily tag a suffix to each df based on a set of labels for columns that are common, but that is less important. Is the above merge operation something that can be done more elegantly in pandas or that already exists as a builtin?

Comment: What a fun exception! Do you think you could give a small example of what you would like (e.g. a couple of small dataframes and their desired output from mymerge).

Comment: @hayden: see my edit - i gave an example

Comment: suffixes doesn't seem to do anything in your `merge1` example (is it needed?)

Comment: might want to try passing `right_index=True` and `left_index=True`.  Are you merging by the index?

Comment: At the moment, [joining a list of dataframes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) is not supported with suffixes, will have a go adding it later this week.

Comment: Your merges are going to be made on overlapping column names-- is that what you want? Could you look inside the function where the error occurs and let me know what the value of the `group_sizes` variable is before the error occurs? The cardinality of the "join space" is the issue and may need to be worked around.

Comment: I want to make sure you know that these are SQL-style joins with full row duplication etc. Is that what you want?

Comment: @WesMcKinney: Yes, I want an outer join but I want it to use the indices of the left and right df. I now pass it ``left_index=True`` and ``right_index=True`` and that gets rid of the combinatorial explosion but still does not do what I intended. I just want to combine all the dfs (they all share an index) and for the overlapping column names, use the suffixes in the suffixes list.

Comment: @WesMcKinney,@hayden: updated question to give more info

Comment: @user248237 is it possible to add a pretend `merged.to_dict()`? I'm still not 100% what you want the answer to be!

Comment: @hayden: It's possible in the sense that there's always a unique index for all the dfs in question. I can explain what's unclear if you let me know what - I basically want an outer merge that adds columns together based on a unique index

Comment: This has been fixed in pandas v0.10.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of your method:

```
In [29]: merged
Out[29]: 
         bob_id1  gender john_id1 bob_id2 mary_id1 mary_id2
employee                                                   
bob            a    male      NaN       b      NaN      NaN
john         NaN    male        x     NaN      NaN      NaN
mary         NaN  female      NaN     NaN        c        d
```

A solution with pandas built-in [`df.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html?highlight=combine_first#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first):

```
In [28]: reduce(lambda x,y: x.combine_first(y), [df1, df2, df3])
Out[28]: 
         bob_id1 bob_id2  gender john_id1 mary_id1 mary_id2
employee                                                   
bob            a       b    male      NaN      NaN      NaN
john         NaN     NaN    male        x      NaN      NaN
mary         NaN     NaN  female      NaN        c        d
```

To add a suffix to the columns of each frame, I'd suggest renaming the columns before calling `combine_first`.

On the other hand, you may want to look into an operation like `pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys=['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], axis=1)`, which produces a dataframe with MultiIndex columns.  In this case, may want to consider making gender part of the index or live with it's duplication.

Comment: thank you, the ``reduce/combine_first`` solution is best and I agree that renaming the dfs before combining is the elegant solution. Can you explain though why this does not cause combinatorial issues while merge does? From the documentation, this seems like an outer join on an index with merge, but they behave very differently...

Comment: Good question -- it seems to be a limitation of the current merge implementation.  Opened github issue https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2690 to follow up on Wes's question above.

Answer (score 1):

from the sourcecode:

```
max_groups = 1L
for x in group_sizes:
    max_groups *= long(x)

if max_groups > 2**63:  # pragma: no cover
    raise Exception('Combinatorial explosion! (boom)')
```

And, in the [same file](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/source/browse/src/python/pandas/PLATLIB/pandas/tools/merge.py?repo=xy-27&r=f2b689fd6745c956cf9801c6cf6598707d158846)

```
# max groups = largest possible number of distinct groups
left_key, right_key, max_groups = self._get_group_keys()
```

The line `max_groups *= long(x)` indicates that it is not additive, thus critical.